# Duplicated symbol error when changing to Release

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've been working normally in Debug scheme, now I changed to Release and Im having this error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FMDatabase in /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-eotzriquwrojfrgwpqxtmjmoyrlq/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libMapView.a(FMDatabase.o) and /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-eotzriquwrojfrgwpqxtmjmoyrlq/Build/Intermediates/XXX.build/Release-iphonesimulator/XXX.build/Objects-normal/i386/FMDatabase.o for architecture i386
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two classes called FMDatabase, or more likely, you have one class but you are trying to link its object file twice.  My guess would be, you have included the `.m` file in the project but you also have a library with it in.

Comment: Ok, but why it happens when I change to Release? It has been working correctly until now

Comment: @Antonio MG: No idea.  Perhaps your Release config is screwed up but your Debug config isn't.

Comment: For what Im checking in the code, probably libMapView is using FMDatabase, and Im also importing it in my main project, could it bE?

Comment: @AntonioMG:  that sounds like it could be.  A quick Google suggests it is in libMapview.

Comment: Ok, I just confirmed it, libMapView is using also FMDatabase, so right now in 2 diferent parts of my project Im using it, but I how can i get ride of only one?